# Employer does not withhold state taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax

I live in GA where there is a state income tax. I work in TN where there is no income state tax. My company does not operate a business in GA and are telling me they cannot withhold GA taxes for this reason. Is this accurate?

Comment: Welcome to PF&U. It may well be accurate that your company cannot withhold GA taxes. I suspect what you're asking is what you need to do if they don't?

Comment: "*Is this accurate?*" If they do their own payroll, and you're the only GA employee, then they very well might not be set up to do it.  But if they use a service bureau (like ADP), then the bureau would do it automatically.  (If they have a local bookkeeper do it, they might not be paying him/her to do that much extra work for one person.)

Comment: Interesting question. My employer is in another state, I am the only employee in this state, and my employer withholds state taxes. Maybe they are not required to do so?

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by the comments to the question (credit: [RonJohn](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/22266/ronjohn)), if the TN company has no GA presence then they may not **need** to setup GA payroll/income tax withholdings. It may be more of a question of not wanting to deal with the paperwork/red ink/bureaucracy of paying state taxes for a single employee, who could decide to move elsewhere in the future.

Instead, you are most likely responsible for making [estimated tax payments to the state of GA](https://dor.georgia.gov/documents/500-es-individual-and-fiduciary-estimated-tax-payment-voucher), for the amount that would normally be withheld from your gross income.